# what is the different between memmove and c++11 std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the different between `memmove` and c++11 `std::move`? Can I use `std::move` on overlapped memory location? And which method has the higher speed performance?

Comment: std::move doesn't actually move anything whereas memmove does. std::move just creates an rvalue-reference which can be moved from.

Comment: @Tom `std::move` does move things http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move, while `memmove` doesn't (it just copies)!

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes My bad, I though he was referring to the other [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

Comment: This question would be clearer if it specified which `std::move` you were referring to:  The one taking 3 arguments instead of the one taking one argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few ways:

1. std::move invokes assignment operators, while memmove does not. As such, memmove is not appropriate for non-POD types.
2. std::move will work on any C++ container type, while memmove will only work on those which store elements linearly in contiguous memory locations (such as with arrays and std::vector).
3. std::move is not appropriate for a destination range which overlaps the source range on the left (use move_backwards for that), while memmove is appropriate for all overlapping ranges.

In situations where you're copying POD types to a right-overlapping range, it is likely that memmove and std::move will have similar performance. In all other situations, only one of the two is appropriate, so you can't really compare performance.

Comment: <nit> `std::move` performs a move assignment, which typically invokes a move assignment or copy assignment operator.  Assignment operators that invoke constructors or destructors are possible, but generally considered bad style.  The spirit of your comment is correct: `memmove` just shuffles bytes, whereas `std::move` respects the special members of the types involved.  Just the detail of invoking constructors/destructors instead of assignment operators is incorrect.